# prevent the deletion or edition of entity with a listener

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, easyadmin

I'm using **easy-admin** in a **Symfony** application. 
My entity are managed through **Doctrine**.

I have an entity `fieldTemplate` linked to entity `Field` and `Position` through a *Many-To-One* relationship.

```php
// App\Entity\FieldTemplate.php

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\FieldTemplateRepository")
 */
class FieldTemplate
{

    /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Position", mappedBy="fieldTemplate", cascade={"persist"}, orphanRemoval=true)
    */
    private $positions;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Field", mappedBy="template", cascade={"persist"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $fields;
}
```

```php
// App\Entity\Field.php

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\FieldRepository")
 */
class Field
{
    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\FieldTemplate", inversedBy="fields", cascade={"persist"})
    */
    private $template;
}
```

```php
// App\Entity\Position.php

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\PositionRepository")
 */
class Position
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\FieldTemplate", inversedBy="positions")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $fieldTemplate;
}
```

Using a *Listener* I'd like to prevent the removal or edition of the template if `fields` are already linked to it and force the user to create a new one.

```php
// app\Listener\FieldTemplateListener.php

class FieldTemplateListener
{
    public function preUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getObject();

        if($entity instanceof FieldTemplate)
        {
            if (count($entity->getFields()))
                throw new AccessDeniedException("this template has already field it cannot be changed");
        }
    }

    public function preRemove(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getObject();

        if($entity instanceof FieldTemplate)
        {
            if(count($entity->getFields()))
                throw new AccessDeniedException('this template has already fields it cannot be removed');
        }
    }
}
```

it is registered in my `services`

```
#App\config\services.yaml

services:
    App\EventListener\FieldTemplateListener:
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: preRemove, priority: 500 }
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: preUpdate, priority: 500 }
```

When I try to delete a template, the error is thrown but both `positions` and `fields` are removed and when I try to edit, the error isn't thrown....

Does someone see what I did wrong ?

Comment: Are you listeners called? is preRemove function called? Did you check https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/v2.4.x/lib/Gedmo/SoftDeleteable/SoftDeleteableListener.php#L45 ?

Comment: yes my listeners are called for the `preRemove` for the `preUpdate`, as no changes has been performed to `FieldTemplate` only `field`and `position` listeners are called.

Comment: Try getting the entity manager `$em = $args->getEntityManager(); ` and use `$em->detach($entity);` and tell me the results

Comment: same behaviour, it means that the other entities are removed before the `fieldTemplate` right ?